# How to get the text box on the right under the picture

Tags: php, html, css, image, text

[image]

As you can see in the picture, there is a box to the right with some text and a lot of white space.
My goal is to have the text under the pictures while I have 3 pictures in a row that are nicely aligned.
When I try this either the pictures aren't aligned anymore or the pictures aren't cropped anymore.
I wanted every picture with the same size and still sharp but, then this issue came up.

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

form {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

form div {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#img_div {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    border: 2px solid #d8680c;
    float: left;
}

#img_div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

img {
    float: left;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

#pictext {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```
<div id="content">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        echo "<img src='fotopage\images/" . $row['image'] . "' >";
        echo "<p id='pictext'>" . $row['image_text'] . "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use the same `id`s for multiple elements, `id`s need to be unique on a page

Comment: @kerbh0lz i do this because i upload picture's to a database so they show on my webpage so they always get the same ID

Comment: They _all_ have the same id, which is invalid!

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of using ID

ID must be unique and when you do the loop there will be some other divs with same ID

add it like this

```
 <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div class='img_div'>";
        echo "<img src='fotopage\images/" . $row['image'] . "' >";
        echo "<p class='pictext'>" . $row['image_text'] . "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

make sure to reflect them via JS or JQuery depends on what your are using

Comment: Hello and thank you for your commend!
As you can see i always give a picture the id img_div because i upload the pictures to this page.
Will a class fix this issue? because they will still have the same styling etc.

Comment: I tried it. and then all my styling isn't working anymore (i did change the id for a class in css) all the pictures are inside eachother and the borders aren't showing anymore

Comment: well yes you should change the ID's for styling to classes also
ex:
#img_div{
left:10px;
}

well be 
.img_div{
left:10px;
}

Comment: #img_div{ left:10px; } well be .img_div{ left:10px; }
This i know and i did this aswell but all my styling isnt working if i change this